# How to connect to MongoDB from iOS (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, realm

I have developed an iOS application using RealmSwift.
This works fine so far.
Now, as I'm getting closer to publishing into App Store, I wanted to set up some cloud configuration to be able to connect to a cloud database, but I just got totally confused.

A couple of weeks ago I saw Realm Cloud as an option. Now I only see MongoDB Realm - or something like that. I digged into a bit, and found that there are three components: Realm DB, Realm Sync and Mongo DB Atlas.

If my understanding is correct, I have to create an Atlas Cluster, on which my Realm Database will be hosted and to which I will be able to connect and sync. Am I correct?

My main problem is that I have no idea how to connect it to my existing code. I don't want user authentication or anything from MongoDB, I have my own, I basically have a DB only, which I want to sync and connect to. So, currently in the code I usually use:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
   ...
}
```

How can I update it to use the MongoDB in the Atlas Cloud? I went through their 'tutorials' but I'm still way too confused.

I see a `Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration)` init function, but if I should use that one, how should I get a Realm.Configuration object?

Also, what does partition key means?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your confusion is justified. The docs and tutorials are still a work in progress and a bit disjointed. I think over time it will improve.

SO is not a good place for a full tutorial but here's a very high level overview.

A link to the tutorial - [iOS Swift Tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/ios-swift/)

Go through the Cocoapods install

1) Your going to create a Cluster in the MongoDB console

2) Within that cluster you're create a Realm 'app'

3) Within that Realm 'app' you're going to set up:

- Sync (development mode)
- Users->Providers->Email/Password Authentication

Your app will have an AppId, which can be found in the Atlas console on the left, right next to the app name (it's a document button you can click on to copy).

Then, in you XCode Realm project, you'll set it up using cocoapods to install RealmSwift.

Now to your question:

> how to connect it to my existing code.

Add a struct, which is the connection string to you Atlas Realm project

import RealmSwift

```
struct Constants {
    // Set this to your Realm App ID found in the Realm UI.
    static let REALM_APP_ID = "your app id"
}
```

then, when you want to authentication, you'll do this

```
let app = RealmApp(id: Constants.REALM_APP_ID)
app.login(withCredential: AppCredentials(username: username, password: password)) { user, error in
```

once you've authenticated, to access realm use this

```
guard let user = app.currentUser() else {
   fatalError("Must be logged in to access this view")
}

let realm = try! Realm(configuration: user.configuration(partitionValue: user.identity!))
```

Comment: Thank you! Do I have to set Email/Password authentication? I'm handling users in my own DB table and don't want to use the method provided by MongoDB. Can I skip this, and use the anonymous login from the app?

Or is it better to create one user with email/password, which would be an application username/password which would be used every time just to get an app instance?

Comment: Or, as I see there is a way to have APIkey as well, can I use that within my app to connect? Maybe something like 
app.login(withApiKey: ???)

And upon opening the app for the first time, will it create the data model in MongoDB? Or shall I import somehow from the source code / default.realm file? I would prefer not creating all tables manually as they are already created in the code.

Comment: @zdtorok Great questions. I would encourage you to leverage the authentication MongoDB provides as it's secure and gives you far tighter control over user signups etc. But yes, you could use anonymous auth. I would discourage using a single email/pw auth. In going through the Getting Started Guide, it has you pre-create your schema. I would suggest skipping that section. When setting up the app in console, Sync section on the left hand side and then Select the right tab of “Define your Schema as you go”  - this will enable Developer Mode which will create the schema from the app.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I still get an error in Xcode.
`let app = RealmApp(id: Constants.REALM_APP_ID)` gives an Xcode error: 'Argument passed to call that takes no arguments'.
In my Podfil I have 
`pod 'RealmSwift', '=10.0.0-alpha.4'.
Any idea?

Comment: I could connect, the problem was that I should use 10.0.0-beta2 instead!

Comment: Based on your previous comments I was finally able to connect to it and seems to be almost working, thanks!
One last thing that I couldn't overcome yet: app.login seems to be async, but in AppDelegate when I filter for an object, it returns nil, seems to be as if the async login was not finished yet. Is there a way to perform 'normal' login and not async? My approach is that I have one REALM object in the Constanst struct, and use that to read/write - which in general seems to be working fine - except this case in AppDelegate.

Comment: @zdtorok The pattern would be to present the user with a login view. Once they supply their login credentials, the `app.login(withCredential:` is called. Within that closure, if it's successfull, proced to the next new the user should be using, a tasks list for example. If login failed, notify the user and go back to the login view. As you can see, with that pattern you leveraging the asynchronous nature of the following closure.

Comment: How did you move your Legacy Realm Data to your MongoDB Atlas?

Comment: @half_stack We wrote a little data transfer app that reads in existing realm data, updates  them with the correct partition and write them out. There's a bunch of other ways but our structure was fairly simple with just a few relationships.

Comment: Hello Jay, thanks for the reply. Did you do all this using just RealmSwift SDK?

Comment: @half_stack Well, there's Realm (v5.x) and then there's MongoDB Realm (10.x) so there's not a specific 'RealmSwift'. Keep in mind that MongoDB Realm is BETA and it's still VERY Beta at this point (IMO) with a lot of server level issues that still need to be ironed out. I would not suggest it for production or even pre-production at this time. If you want to play around with it, now's a good time to get familiar with the SDK and the server functions. The answer is yes, I opened my existing local realm with a config pointing to that and then created MongoDB Realm objects from those to sync.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Realm as anything other than an embedded database inside the iOS app. If you need to store something on the server side you should implement an API that does the writing to your MongoDB (or whatever database you use). Connecting the iOS app directly to a server side database seems like an anti-pattern to me.

Comment: Isn't Realm Sync is that in the middle? I had the understanding that with Realm I don't have to implement own server-side API or anything. Write the code, use Realm Cloud (or now MongoDB/Atlas Cloud?), configure it, and it stores the database in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Realm Sync connects to the Atlas deployment as needed to synchronize the data. My understanding is you do not need to connect to Atlas directly in your code.

[Documentation](https://docs.realm.io/sync/realm-sync-a-primer/realm-sync-the-details) provides some information and a few pages down there is sample code.

Comment: Thanks, I checked the documentation already but the example code (https://docs.realm.io/sync/getting-started-1/step-1-my-first-realm-app) is not working either - seems to be outdated, Xcode fails to build.

Comment: If you are having an issue with the provided code you can ask that in a question.