# How to integrate Google Sign In with Realm iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, realm, google-signin

I've built out most of my app after following steps on https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/quick-start/ which previously instructed us to use cocoa-pod RealmSwift version 10.0.0-beta.2

I was attempting to implement the sample code here https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/authenticate/#ios-login-google
and noticed many of the function and class names differ (not sure if it is referencing 5.3.6).

I was digging into the repo on Github and noticed that 10.0.0-beta.4 has new code and examples for integrating "Sign in With Apple" so it's possible RealmSwift just doesn't fully support all authentication methods yet that are supported within Mongo Atlas

My code from the quick start tutorial for sign in was

```
app.login(withCredential: AppCredentials(username: username!, password: password!)) { [weak self](user, error) in
```

Which ran fine of course, however the following code

```
let gToken = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.currentUser.authentication.idToken
app.login(withCredential: AppCredentials.init(googleToken: gToken!)) { [weak self](user, error) in
```

Complains that it can't compile because it's expecting `AppCredentials(username: username!, password: password!)`
Even though AppCredentials.init(googleToken is a valid call that returns the RLMCredentials object

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62375536/how-to-connect-to-mongodb-from-ios-swift)?

Comment: The code in the question doesn't appear to match the code in the MongoDB Realm guide `app.login(credentials: Credentials(googleToken: "<token>")`. Go to [Authenticate a user](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/authenticate/) and scroll down to Google Authentication (this is the same link as in your question so it's not clear why your code is not matching). It may be a minor thing but good to double check that.

Comment: *note, from 10.0.0-beta.2 to 10.0.0-beta.4, the entire sign in process was overhauled (changed) which explains why the code in the question doesn't match the documentation.

Comment: @cora I already have email/password working, what I am trying to do is replace it with Google Sign in as long term I do not want to be storing and managing passwords

Comment: @Jay Yes that is what's going on as far as code call mismatch, however all of those examples are for authenticating if the user already exists I assume, I did not see sample code for if a user has never connected before.  It's possible it automatically handles adding a user account if they've never signed in with their 3rd party token before, but the documentation doesn't make that clear.